# Xmpp relogin due to a broadcast receiver network change

Tags: xmpp

I´m developing a XMMP android client with a smack, the problem is that the login delay too,
When I launch the first connection run well, but I have a broadcast receiver to listen network changes, and when I stop the connection and relaunch it due to a changes of networks, the server delay too and sometime can´t login in to the server!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a session attachment! This is by far the most robust way of establishing an xmpp connection the next time you reconnect it again.